# What are the equivalents between US crochet stitch terms and UK terms?

Tags: crocheting, terminology

I have heard that the names of stitches are different between the US and UK.

If I have a pattern from the UK, how do I convert it to the US terms or vice versa?

Answer (score 7):

Fortunately, if you are familiar with reading charted patterns, the icons are the same, so the only issue is if you don't know how to read charts or if you prefer to read written out patterns.

A couple of the terms are the same - "chain stitch" and "slip stitch". Most of the rest can be somewhat easy to remember if you can remind yourself that the UK has no "single crochet", so most of the numbers are incremented up one in the UK version:

#### US Term ----------------------- UK Term

```
chain ----------------------- chain
slip stitch ----------------- slip stitch
single crochet -------------- double crochet
half double crochet --------- half treble crochet
double crochet -------------- treble crochet
treble crochet -------------- double treble crochet
double treble crochet ------- triple treble crochet
front post double crochet --- raised front treble crochet
back post double crochet ---- raised back treble crochet
fasten off/bind off --------- cast off
skip ------------------------ miss
gauge ----------------------- tension
yarn over ------------------- yarn over hook
```

Comment: Is it worth a separate question to cover common shortforms?

Comment: @Matt You mean the abbreviations? I'd been thinking of adding them here but hadn't. I can certainly do that. If you mean a question like "What does "hdc" mean in my crochet pattern?" with an answer that explains all of the abbreviations to full terms, that could be its own question, I think.

Comment: I'll ask the question then. Been one I was thinking of. This just reminded me.

Comment: I've seen UK English use 'single crochet' in place of slip stitch.